# How do I get the right wireless modules to load at startup for a BCM4322?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, blacklist

I have been troubleshooting my HP EliteBook with BCM4322 14e4:432b wireless card.  I am using Linux kernel 3.9 and I have almost found the solution.  Reading on the Linux Wireless site, I found that the b43 and wl drivers should work at least somewhat with the card.  I was unable to get things working using kmod-wl, and so I moved on to working with b43.  I followed the guide here, and got it working using these lines of code:

```
modprobe -r b43 bcma
modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
modprobe -r wl
modprobe b43
```

When I restart the computer, I have to do this again to get things working.  I know I am supposed to blacklist the unwanted modules, but adding brcmsmac and wl to the blacklist.conf file does not seem to work.  How can I get this to work permanently?

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean to answer, merely wanted to ask this in a comment, but I do not yet have enough reputation to be able to comment. When you added `brcmsmac` and `wl` to `blacklist.conf` - Did you add them as `install brcmsmac /bin/false` or `blacklist brcmsmac` ? What happens if you try the other method?

Comment: I think I have found that my problem is that b43 is not loading at startup.  I only have brcmsmac and wl blacklisted and b43 does not load at startup.  I am going to try a fresh OS install, update, and then try again.  I had originally tried using the proprietary driver first and I think that messed things up.

Comment: SOLVED: I did a fresh OS install, followed directions on http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 and blacklisted only ssb.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I've looked through the answer at the above duplicate-as-marked URL, but found it circuitous in regard to the very specific problem of having to modprobe b43 every boot.  The answer for my system was simple: broadcom-sta-common blacklists the b43 module, so purging the broadcom-sta-* files instantly resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the blacklisting does not work then the module might be loaded early in the initframfs. Take a look at the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`.

What is the content of `/etc/modules`? Also please post the lines you used to blacklist the modules.

br

**Update:**

I found the following command on the [b43 homepage](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43):

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Have you tried that?

On the other hand, if you want to have your module loaded at run-time, add the following line to `/etc/modules`:

`b43`

to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`blacklist brcmsmac` and `blacklist wl`

then reboot the machine.

The module *should* be loaded then.

Comment: Both are empty.